# Computing the integral $\int_{|z|=1}z^ne^z~dz$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

> Compute
> $$\int_{|z|=1}z^ne^z~dz$$ for $n\in \Bbb Z$.

My thought is that we need to consider when $n$ is a negative integer so the singularity is $0$.

Then let $f_1(z)= z^{n+1}e^z.$

$$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{z^{n+1}e^z}{z-0}~dz = 2\pi if_1(0)=0.$$

Is this correct?

When $n\ge0, f\in H(\triangle)$, so the integral is $0$. Am I right about that?

Comment: If $n$ is a negative integer, then $f_1(0)$ either doesn't exist or it's $1$, so no, it cannot be correct.

Comment: You are right. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do I need to separate it into two cases and evaluate

Comment: Do you know a more general form of the CIF?  Or maybe you know about integrating $z^n$ on the contour $|z|=1$ (_a la_ residues)?

Comment: Yes I'm aware of both... The more general form - do you mean the one that starts with assuming g defined on the boundary so it doesn't use holomorphic function? Is using residue theorem only for n negative?

Comment: The residue theorem works generally but is trivial for positive n in this case (it gives 0=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case when $n$ is non-negative you are correct about, as then the integrand is an entire function.

Suppose now that $n$ is negative, and let $m=-n$. Then the integral we want to evaluate is

$$I=\int_{\lvert z\rvert =1}\frac{e^z}{z^m}~\mathrm{d}z.$$

Now clearly $z\mapsto\frac{e^{z}}{z^m}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, and so by the Residue theorem,

$$I=2\pi i\mathop{\operatorname{Res}}_{z=0}\frac{e^z}{z^m}.$$

But notice that we have the Laurent expansion

$$\frac{e^z}{z^m}=\frac{1}{z^m}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{z^j}{j!}=\sum_{j=-m}^\infty\frac{z^j}{(j+m)!},$$

which means that

$$\mathop{\operatorname{Res}}_{z=0}\frac{e^z}{z^m}=\frac{1}{(m-1)!}.$$

Thus

$$\int_{\lvert z\rvert =1}\frac{e^z}{z^m}~\mathrm{d}z=\frac{2\pi i}{(m-1)!}.$$